# my autocomplete is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

myautocomple is not working in codeiginiter
even my chrome debugger --> network --> is showing the proper result.
here is my code for view file:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control select_group product" style="text-transform: uppercase;" id="gang" name="gang" placeholder="Gangman Name" autocomplete="off" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">            
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#gang" ).autocomplete({
source: "<?php echo base_url('Issue/getGangName/?');?>",
minLength: 3
});
});
</script>
```

here is my controller function

```
public function GetGangName()
{
  $this->load->model('Issuemodel');
  $gangdata=$this->Issuemodel->GetGang();        
  echo json_encode($gangdata);
}
```

Comment: Welcome. What do you mean "doesn't work"? Nothing happens when you type 3 characters? Please show what your json looks like.

Comment: Actually it is showing the box but not showing the data in it. Here is my json:- [{"gang_name":" NARAYAN SINGH CHUNDAWAT MLS"},{"gang_name":" RADHESHYAM SARGRA RMCH 2"},{"gang_name":" TRILOK CHANDRA SUTHAR RMCH 2"},{"gang_name":"ASLAM KHAN"},{"gang_name":"BHARAT SINGH"},{"gang_name":"Bhrth Raj Mehta RMCH 2"},{"gang_name":"CHANDRA PAL SINGH"},{"gang_name":"Deepak sharma"},{"gang_name":"DEVI LAL KACHI"},{"gang_name":"GAANGA SINGH RATHORE"}]

Answer (score 0):

As per [jQuery UI Autocomplete's docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), your PHP handler should return data with a form like that:

```
[
  "NARAYAN SINGH CHUNDAWAT MLS",
  "RADHESHYAM SARGRA RMCH 2",
  // ...
]
```

or a form like that:

```
[
  { "label": "some label", "value": "NARAYAN SINGH CHUNDAWAT MLS" },
  { "label": "some label", "value": "RADHESHYAM SARGRA RMCH 2" },
  // ...
];
// Note: should work with only the "value" key if you don't need the labels
```

**Sample using raw data** (I just changed the relevant chunk of code):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gang").autocomplete({
      source: [{
        "value": "NARAYAN SINGH CHUNDAWAT MLS"
      }, {
        "value": "RADHESHYAM SARGRA RMCH 2"
      }, {
        "value": "TRILOK CHANDRA SUTHAR RMCH 2"
      }, {
        "value": "ASLAM KHAN"
      }, {
        "value": "BHARAT SINGH"
      }, {
        "value": "Bhrth Raj Mehta RMCH 2"
      }, {
        "value": "CHANDRA PAL SINGH"
      }, {
        "value": "Deepak sharma"
      }, {
        "value": "DEVI LAL KACHI"
      }, {
        "value": "GAANGA SINGH RATHORE"
      }],
      minLength: 3
    });
  });
</script>

<input type="text" class="form-control select_group product" style="text-transform: uppercase;" id="gang" name="gang" placeholder="Gangman Name" autocomplete="off">
```